# Material design: drawing attention to a floating action button

Tags: user-behavior, user-centered-design, material-design, google-materials-design

I've a design which I need to create a first time user experiance on creating an application.

[image]

The Floating Action Button needs to get highlighted on the very first time a user gets logged into the system. What is the recommended way in material design to do such a thing?

Comment: Material Design guidelines for onboarding can be found in Onboarding section of the Material Design: https://material.io/guidelines/growth-communications/onboarding.html#onboarding-quickstart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can draw more attention to creating a first application if you make more use of your empty states. Rather than leaving users on a screen saying they haven't done something yet, you should instead encourage them to do something. To do this, consider adding more enticing copy and connect your 'getting started' button to this copy.

[image: material design quick start]

Here you see both a reason to start (if you add a report you can analyse) and the button is highlighted.

[image]

With some layout altering, you can also add the button to a structural element within a sheet to get the copy and action button closer together for better coherence.

More here: https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-large-screens